# Kusto make-series by month

Tags: kql

I'm really struggling to figure out how to use the Kusto make-series function but output the results by month. The current example below is set to 1d (i.e. 1 day).

I understand that month and year is not a valid operator for timespan, so looking for a way around this.

```
let startDateTime = datetime(2022-04-13T08:25:51.000Z);
let endDateTime = datetime(2022-04-19T21:25:51.876Z);
let m = materialize(traces | where timestamp > startDateTime and timestamp < endDateTime
| extend Message=parse_json(message)
| extend LogLevel = Message.LogLevel,
LogEventCategory = Message.LogEventCategory,
LogEventType = Message.LogEventType,
LogEventSource = Message.LogEventSource,
LogData = Message.LogData,
LogUserId = Message.LogUserId,
LogUsername = Message.LogUsername,
LogForename = Message.LogForename,
LogSurname = Message.LogSurname,
LogCountry = Message.LogCountry,
LogRegionName = Message.LogRegionName,
LogCity = Message.LogCity,
LogZip = Message.LogZip,
LogLatitude = Message.LogLatitude,
LogLongitude = Message.LogLongitude,
LogIsp = Message.LogIsp,
LogIpAddress = Message.LogIpAddress,
LogMobile = Message.LogMobile);
m | where Message.LogLevel == 'Information' | where Message.LogEventCategory == 'WebApp-CLIENT'
| make-series counter=count() default=0 on timestamp in range(startDateTime, endDateTime, 1d); // Need to define 1month, NOT 1d
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you use the `summarize` operator instead of `make-series`? that would allow you to count by `startofmonth(datetime_column_name)`

for example:

[click to run](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA22PMQ7CMAxFdyTuYLZEolLSCgQDhwmNSysRG7muCojDkxYm6Oj3/vAsgS4IUaERThAubKr9LlpQBuLRWOgVb+DjevUCvCtShMSkLZyyCaLczKeJaqfJ2KLgd7HpyMSgqF1CU7qyLFxVOG+38EP9P/WFd0vUHRfpYaJzQD+kFKR7ItQ8kOYHzo9Pz2Ql96NkdR0S1W3ufwPnzq1HAAEAAA==)

```
range dt from ago(365d) to now() step 1d
| extend month = startofmonth(dt)
// the following line skips a few months, for the purpose of the example
| where month !in(datetime(2022-03-01), datetime(2022-01-01), datetime(2021-10-01), datetime(2021-09-01), datetime(2021-08-01))
| summarize count() by month
| render columnchart
```

[image]

alternatively, if that doesn't meet your scenario - you can create the list of all months between the minimum & maximum values of your datetime column, and perform an outer join between that and the summarize above

for example (this outputs the exact same column chart as shown above):

```
let T = range dt from ago(365d) to now() step 1d;
let min_max = toscalar(T | summarize pack_array(min(dt), max(dt)));
let min = todatetime(min_max[0]);
let max = todatetime(min_max[1]);
T
| extend month = startofmonth(dt)
// the following line skips a few months, for the purpose of the example
| where month !in(datetime(2022-03-01), datetime(2022-01-01), datetime(2021-10-01), datetime(2021-09-01), datetime(2021-08-01))
| summarize count() by month
| join kind = rightouter (
    range dt from min to max step 20d
    | summarize by month = startofmonth(dt)
) on month
| project month = coalesce(month, month1), count_ = coalesce(count_, 0)
| render columnchart
```

Comment: Hi, I chose make-series becuase I wanted to return a default value of zero if no results were found for a particular month/day or whatever time intervals I work with, would this still work? thanks

Comment: Using summarize appears to skip any intervals in the output result if the count was zero which unfortunately wouldnt work for my environment, Thanks

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: Would i be able to use this same methodology for other interval operators like day/hour/minute etc? many thanks

Comment: unlike a 'month', those (day/hour/minute) are deterministic timespans, for which you can use `make-series`. but if you choose not to (for whatever reason) - you can replace `| summarize by month = startofmonth(dt)` with `| summarize by bin(dt, <span_of_your_choice>`

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that there is an additional way.

1. Create `make-series` with step of `1d`, but for the `on` clause, instead of using `dt` (the datetime field in my example) use `startofmonth(dt)`.

   This will have the same effect as adding `| extend dt = startofmonth(dt)` before the "standard" `make-series` -
   The summarization of the data will be done for the 1st of every month and every other day will have no data (see image at the bottom).
2. Use `mv-apply` to filter out from the series all days except for the 1st day of every month.

   Theoretically we can skip the use of `make_list` and just leave the series exploded, but then we need to do some other manipulations, including defining the `xcolumn` in the render operator.

---

```
// Generation of a data sample. Not part of the solution.
let t = materialize(range i from 1 to 1000 step 1 | extend dt = ago(365d*rand()) | where getmonth(dt) !in (3,6,9,10,11));
// The solution starts here.
t
| make-series count() on dt = startofmonth(dt) step 1d
| mv-apply count_, dt to typeof(datetime) on (where dt == startofmonth(dt) | summarize make_list(count_), make_list(dt))
| render timechart
```

[image: Start Of Month]

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA22QMU/DMBCF90r9D4/NRmmTqKISQsxsTOyVVV8Sq7Ed2VegKD%20eczLQgdH2e999vrrGGwVKhl0MiB0MrGGDbPw00h7vEZNJXF54IOQ4Xktyv92MxGC8whum5MzofkglE3qCQ5eiRwuOaJumQWaa5DiDvpmChS0900d1OD7ZRylZpbU8fw2UCD2xj4EHZVnjwQWoQ3Wsnqu2qdpW65ftpq7xcScjfFHMKG0R4%201mFqsL7bKIUcY5XgMrDUkuk5d47P6GrH526X3uzDSNt7V0qkpDvsG3iWKnZDXEztPCUqtuQf7DnJGv3pska1lkTqPLrFaqru6uJKzL5CSboYSCPw8C%20wXJU4RXmgEAAA==)

---

This is how it looks without the `mv-apply` part (on a different random data sample).
Please note that all the data is aggregated for the 1st days of the months.

[image: Without mv-apply]

Comment: Thanks for your input, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had already accepted an answer on this but later came up with another alternative which I've tested with the following intervals:

startofyear
startofmonth
startofweek
startofday

Just one side note, startofweek assmes Sunday with int value 0, based on some feedback from comments below i've updated the code with 'startofweek(s-1d)+1d', the example below reflects this with the commented out notes so you can see where i placed this:

```
let startDateTime = datetime(2022-01-1T08:00:00.000Z);
let endDateTime = datetime(2022-04-21T08:00:00.000Z);
let m = materialize(traces | where timestamp > startDateTime and timestamp < endDateTime
| extend Message=parse_json(message)
| extend LogLevel = Message.LogLevel,
LogEventCategory = Message.LogEventCategory,
LogEventType = Message.LogEventType,
LogEventSource = Message.LogEventSource,
LogData = Message.LogData,
LogUserId = Message.LogUserId,
LogUsername = Message.LogUsername,
LogForename = Message.LogForename,
LogSurname = Message.LogSurname,
LogCountry = Message.LogCountry,
LogRegionName = Message.LogRegionName,
LogCity = Message.LogCity,
LogZip = Message.LogZip,
LogLatitude = Message.LogLatitude,
LogLongitude = Message.LogLongitude,
LogIsp = Message.LogIsp,
LogIpAddress = Message.LogIpAddress,
LogMobile = Message.LogMobile);
m | where Message.LogLevel == 'Information' | where Message.LogEventCategory == 'WebApp-CLIENT'
| summarize Count=count() by timestamp=startofweek(timestamp-1d)+1d // so week starts on Monday
| join kind=rightouter (
        range s from startDateTime to endDateTime step 1d 
        | summarize by timestamp = startofweek(s-1d)+1d // so week starts on Monday
    ) on timestamp
    | project timestamp=coalesce(timestamp, timestamp1), Count = coalesce(Count, 0)
```

[image]

Next example using startofmonth

```
let startDateTime = datetime(2022-03-20T20:00:00.000Z);
let endDateTime = datetime(2022-04-20T21:00:00.000Z);
let m = materialize(traces | where timestamp > startDateTime and timestamp < endDateTime
| extend Message=parse_json(message)
| extend LogLevel = Message.LogLevel,
LogEventCategory = Message.LogEventCategory,
LogEventType = Message.LogEventType,
LogEventSource = Message.LogEventSource,
LogData = Message.LogData,
LogUserId = Message.LogUserId,
LogUsername = Message.LogUsername,
LogForename = Message.LogForename,
LogSurname = Message.LogSurname,
LogCountry = Message.LogCountry,
LogRegionName = Message.LogRegionName,
LogCity = Message.LogCity,
LogZip = Message.LogZip,
LogLatitude = Message.LogLatitude,
LogLongitude = Message.LogLongitude,
LogIsp = Message.LogIsp,
LogIpAddress = Message.LogIpAddress,
LogMobile = Message.LogMobile);
m | where Message.LogLevel == 'Information' | where Message.LogEventCategory == 'WebApp-CLIENT'
| summarize Count=count() by timestamp=startofmonth(timestamp)
| join kind=rightouter (
        range s from startDateTime to endDateTime step 1d 
        | summarize by timestamp = startofmonth(s)
    ) on timestamp
    | project timestamp=coalesce(timestamp, timestamp1), Count = coalesce(Count, 0)
```

From the help and answers given by others, it seems there's various different ways in answering the question. I'm not claiming to be an expert by any means and there may be better solutions, but from my own testing above, I seem to getting the desired results now. Thanks to everyone for their input.

Comment: Should be `startofweek(s-1d)+1d` so each Sunday would be considered as the last  day of the previous week

Comment: How is this solution different from that of @Yoni L.?

Comment: I'e updated my answer to reflect your suggestions, thanks

Comment: For fixed size intervals (e g. 7d, 1h, 15m, 90s etc.) you can simply use `make-series` in a straightforward manner. Only for non fixed intervals (e g. 1st of every month) you need a different approach